# How to decode open id connect server Acess token in Web API core

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I am working with ASOS ( Asp.net.OpenIDConnect.Server) and using bearer authentication.

I need to check token expiry time and update it.

Not able to decode access token. Can please any one share the way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which derives from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`:

```
var token = "YourToken";
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
var expire= jsonToken.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "exp").Value;
```

Update :

If you are referring to the Opaque tokens ,  which are encrypted and signed by the authorization server using the ASP.NET Core Data Protection stack. Then you are using the [`AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation` middleware](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation) or an [`introspection` middleware](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection) . For the AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation middleware , i think you can check the claims in one of the `OAuthValidationEvents` such as `OnCreateTicket` event .

If you are concern about the expire token of access tokens . The recommended way is to use refresh token to issue new access token if the token is expired .

The refresh token default expiration date can be set globally from the options, using the `RefreshTokenLifetime` property. If you don't provide your own lifetime, they are valid for 14 days.

Note that sliding expiration is also enabled by default, which means you get a new refresh token (valid for 14 days) each time you make a new `grant_type=refresh_token` request. You can disable sliding expiration by setting `UseSlidingExpiratio`n to false.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35747870/5751404

Comment: In open id connect the access token is not jwt, so we can't decode this way. Although i am using bearer authentication.

Comment: Yes you are right , i found the solution on https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/issues/500. and you are referring the same.