# AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server Token Revocation and Logout is not working

Tags: openid, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, openiddict, aspnet-contrib

I have configured both **revoke and logout** end points as mentioned below.

```
.AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.LogoutEndpointPath = "/logout";
    options.RevocationEndpointPath = "/revoke";
}
```

But both are not working Token revocation is not expiring/revoking the token.

For **Token Revocation**,
I have debug the code and found that it is rejecting the context in **OpenIdConnectServerHandler** class in below mentioned code.

`var context = new ValidateRevocationRequestContext(Context, Scheme, Options, request); await Provider.ValidateRevocationRequest(context);`

> context.IsRejected is true after above method

The request(post) contains clientId, clientsecret, token as access token or refresh token and token_hint_type. I am not getting to conclusion why this is happening?

**Update 1 :**

Made context validate by below mentioned code.

`public override async Task ValidateRevocationRequest(ValidateRevocationRequestContext context) { context.Validate(); }`

Now i got to know by debugging ASOS code that there is no built in logic for token revocation , am i right ? if this is the scenario then i need to write mine custom logic to revoke the token in

`public override async Task HandleRevocationRequest(HandleRevocationRequestContext context) {.. code }`

Now i am wondering what is the way to revoke the token (access and refresh), because these are self contained and not stored in DB like openiddict( i have looked the revoke logic of openiddict).

Answer (score 0):

> Now i got to know by debugging ASOS code that there is no built in logic for token revocation , am i right ? if this is the scenario then i need to write mine custom logic to revoke the token in

That's right: ASOS is completely stateless.

How you implement that is entirely your own decision. You can use a table to store token entries like OpenIddict (that are created from the `Serialize*Token` events) or a blacklist with the identifiers of the revoked tokens.

More info here: [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server. Refresh tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741269/aspnet-security-openidconnect-server-refresh-tokens/35747870#35747870)